# UIView animate with out time duration

Tags: ios, swift

When swipe , i want navigate between pages with smoothly ( change according to finger moves ) not to navigate with a given time

```
class FirstCustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
   override func perform() {
    // Assign the source and destination views to local variables.
    var firstVCView = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView!
    var secondVCView = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!

    // Get the screen width and height.
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
    secondVCView.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth, 0.0, screenWidth, screenHeight)

    // Access the app's key window and insert the destination view above the current (source) one.
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    window?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)

    // Animate the transition.
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
        firstVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(firstVCView.frame, -screenWidth, 0.0)
        secondVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(secondVCView.frame, -screenWidth, 0.0)

        }) { (Finished) -> Void in
            self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController,
                animated: false,
                completion: nil)
    }
} }
```

Comment: Try with minimum duration as: `0.01`

Comment: Nope , just change screen instantly , i just want to navigate smoothly without time constraint :(

Comment: @ChathurangaSilva You can create a custom interactive gesture animation: http://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to deal with it recently. look at my [github project](https://github.com/TikhonovAlexander/CustomAnimatedTransitioning), maybe it will hepl you.

If a nutshell. You should create class adopts

> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

and implement 2 methods. One for animation's duration, another for your custom animation (moving, fade, and so on).

For example:

```
class ModalPresentAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
    return 0.5
}

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let toVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!
    // ...
    let duration = transitionDuration(transitionContext)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
        toVC.view.frame = // new postion
        }) { finished in

           transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled())
    }
}
```

Then in your ViewController to specify a new ViewControllerTransitioning

```
extension ViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    swipeInteractionController.wireToViewController(presented)
    return modalPresentAnimationController
}
```

But, if you want to add "change according to finger moves" you should create class adopts

> UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition

And in it to use gestureRecognizer.

Comment: layer.transform = transform ... this line shows an error in your github project " Ambiguous use of transform "

Comment: @ChathurangaSilva I use Xcode 7 beta 4 and all work well.

Comment: after create a class , what should i do to              UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in     function, how can i change this ?

Comment: @ChathurangaSilva I've done simple example for you. Here's a link to [example](http://www.filedropper.com/customanimatedtransitioning-master).  I think It will be more clarify. Also you can read similar articles on [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/96062/custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions-swift)